# HttpURLConnection

Tags: httpurlconnection

I want to know in detail about `HttpURLConnection`. I mean how it works for a single connection, multiple connections and all. When I use multiple `InputStream` in a class and close the first `InputStream`, the second `InputStream` is not getting any response from server. That's the reason I want to know in detail about `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Then google `HttpUrlConnection`.

Answer (score -2):

I will tell you this simple, it is just doing his work without to many logic inside. It will work on the thread you open it, and throw exceptions on this thread if it fails. If you want multi - download you just need to open more then one thread.